# c++ _beginthread can't pass string as a parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, parameter-passing, beginthread

I would like to start multiple threads using a sample code like below:

```
void ThreadFunction(void* param) {
    cout << (string)param << endl;
    _endthread();
    }
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        string String = "This is test nr ";
        String += i;
        _beginthread(ThreadFunction, 0, (void*)&String);
        }
    }
```

However, I can't get this to work (***bad allocation error***). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say that you "can't get this to work", what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate? And also please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: what is `_beginthread` ? In what way this code is not working? Are there error message? Does it crash?

Comment: As soon as you reach the `}` at the end of the for-loop, the string goes away.

Comment: @tobi303, it crashes by telling me the `bad alloc` error

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, all I try is to pass a string to a thread. However, I can't get this to work in any way. I get errors like `bad alloc` and such

Comment: Also, you cast the `param` to `string` when it really is a `string*`.

Comment: @BoPersson, the string is not passed by a global reference. Would this be a problem? Could yo provide me a sample?

Comment: No you don't pass a `string` to the thread function, you pass a *pointer* to a `string`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, makes more sense. Sorry, I'm quite new to c++ programming. Could you provide me a simple sample I can work on?

Comment: " it crashes by telling me the bad alloc error " this should be part of the question, not just a comment

Comment: @tobi303, good point. I have added it to the question

Comment: @TVA - If you want to learn C++, and not Windows, you should perhaps look at [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which will copy the parameters to the thread function and not just pass a pointer.

Comment: "new to C++ programming" and "multiple threads" is not an ideal combination. Learn single-threaded C++ programming first. [Book list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @BoPersson, thanks!

Comment: Where is `FunctionName` defined?

Comment: @stefaanv, sorry made a copy-error. Fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a string as you are doing, but you can pass a string pointer.  **BUT!** You have to be careful that the string stays valid at least until the threads starts... This is usually done by creating the strings on the heap, using `new`, but it can also work using global objects.  Here's how your code could work.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <pthread.h>

void ThreadFunction(void* param) 
{
    std::string* s = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(param);  
    cout << *s << endl;  
}                        // <-- no need to call endthread when exiting gracefully

std::vector<std::string> myStrings;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    // since we will use pointers to strings in the vector myStrings,
    // we need to be sure it is final before using them.
    // you could store some form of smart pointer in the vector to avoid 
    // this issue
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
       std::stringstream ss;
       ss << "This is test nr " << i;
       myStrings.emplace_back(ss.str());
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myStrings.size(); i++) 
    {
        _beginthread(FunctionName, 0, &myStrings[i]);
    }

    // we must pause this thread and wait a little while for the threads
    // to run.  _beginthread does not block, and exiting the program too
    // quickly would prevent our background threads from executing...

    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! I got this to work. I however slightly modified the code in order to remove the sleep. I initialize a boolean `ProcessStarted` on `false` just before the `_beginthread`. Within the thread I set `ProcessStarted=true` just after I safely stored the parameter in a string locally for the tread. Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If you are serious about c++, you should really learn how to use the standard library, and start with C++11 or later. The standard library is portable, very practical and is a great time-saver.  C++ has seen a lot of changes in the 2011 standard, and it should be the starting point for any new student, since all major compilers support it..  C++ 14 is the current standard.  There are lots of sites that document the standard library, but I found that cppreference.com is somewhat easier to read.